# Analysis of the contour integration for $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dz \ ze^{-it\sqrt{z^2+m^2}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I come from physics background and unfortunately I think I lack something to do complicated contour integrations. Everything is easy if my integrand involves single branch point located at the origin (i.e. $\sqrt{z}$), however things get more complicated as I consider more than one branch point. Let me demonstrate one example:

Say that I want to compute $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dz \ ze^{-it\sqrt{z^2+m^2}}$ on the $\mathrm{Re}$al axis. I realise that I should do a contour integration. Then I immediately see that it should involve branch points, otherwise I cannot obtain a continuous integrand along the contour even though I close the contour. In many references I see people approach this problem by:
$$
\sqrt{z^2+m^2} = \sqrt{z+im} \sqrt{z-im},
$$

and by substitution:
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{z^2+m^2} &= \sqrt{r_1e^{i\theta_1} r_2e^{i\theta_2}}  \\
&= \sqrt{r_1r_2} e^{i(\theta_1+\theta_2)/2}. 
\end{align}
$$

Then they calculate the following contour:

[plot of the contour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvOA7.png)

In the calculation of the $\Gamma_3$ and the $\Gamma_5$ contours it is said that that we obtain a change of sign over the branch cut, and they subsitute $z = iy$ and perform the calculation. **In the physics books and notes I used, the intermediate steps are not shown.** Therefore, I assume that in the details, they do:

$$
\int_{\Gamma_3} = - \int_\infty^m  (idy) (iy) \ e^{-it\sqrt{r_1r_2}e^{i(\theta_1+\theta_2)/2}} \\
r_1 = |z-im| \\
r_2 = |z+im| \\
$$
Note: The minus sign is due to the path being clockwise along the $\Gamma_3$ with respect to the origin.

Since the product of two absolute values equals to the absolute value of the products, $\sqrt{r_1 r_2} = \sqrt{|z^2+m^2|} = \sqrt{|-y^2+m^2|}$. Moreover along the contour $\Gamma_3$ we have $z=iy \ge im$, thus enabling us to write: $\sqrt{r_1 r_2} = \sqrt{y^2-m^2}$.

$$
\int_{\Gamma_3} = +\int_\infty^m  dy \ y \ e^{-it\sqrt{y^2-m^2}e^{i(\theta_1+\theta_2)/2}}
$$

Now, the last thing to uncover is how do $\theta_{1,2}$ change when we move along the contour. If we pick this path infinitesimally close to the branch cut, along most of this path, we will have: $\theta_{1,2} = \pi/2$. **Is this statement sufficient for us to take its value as $\pi/2$ and not to associate it with the variable of the integraion, i.e. $dz = i dy$?** If so, this will significantly simplify the integration, and let us conclude with:

$$
\int_{\Gamma_3} = -\int^\infty_m  dy \ y \ e^{t\sqrt{y^2-m^2}}
$$

I want to finish with one final question. Although, I understand this method, I don't know why I cannot take the integration variable as $z = Re^{i \theta}$ and continue with:

$$
\int_{\Gamma_3} = - \int (dRe^{i \theta}+iRe^{i \theta}d\theta) (Re^{i \theta}) \ e^{-it\sqrt{R^2e^{2i \theta}+m^2}},
$$

where I make a similar assumption that the line is infinitesimally close to the imaginary axis, and therefore I ignore the $d\theta$ part and take $\theta = \pi/2$ along most of the path and I end up with:

$$
\int_{\Gamma_3} = - \int_\infty^m (dRe^{i \pi}) \ e^{-it\sqrt{R^2e^{\pi i}+m^2}},
$$

and again by similar simplifications:

$$
\int_{\Gamma_3} = - \int^\infty_m dR \ e^{t\sqrt{R^2-m^2}},
$$

However, if I want to do compute the same for the $\Gamma_5$ contour, I cannot obtain the change of sign due to the branch cut, because my integration variable is $dRe^{i\theta}$ which gives the same angle $\theta= \pi/2$ for that contour. **I know that there must be a flaw in this latter method, but I cannot find it.** Can you help me with this? How can I modify it to take it into account the sign change across the branch cut?

Comment: Since your integrand is odd, shouldn't this integral either vanish or fail to converge?

Comment: Oh yes, of course. In quantum field theory in physics there is a factor in the integrand that I did not include here. There should have been an additional $e^{irz}$ factor in the first integrand which in gives a factor of $e^{-ry}$ in the last integral. And by using a prior assumption where r>t, always, we conclude that this integral will eventually vanish but nonzero. This is the only point of computing it in physics. I just want to simplify it as much as possible and find out the missing steps that the physicists go through but not demonstrate. Evaluation is not something that I am after.

Comment: [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/758661) question may be relevant, as it uses the same contour.

Comment: Yes, it is, but does not tell much about the points I am concerned about. It focuses on the arcs whereas I want to understand the behaviour near the branch cut, and which method to use to compute it near the cut and why these methods that I mentioned produce different results. To put it simply: I would like to know how to compute contour integrals in presence of multiple branch cuts and how to determine the sign change.